# Get specific week based upon custom start date (ie Business year)

Tags: php

I was aiming to be able to specify the week from the business fiscal year. I figured setting a specific start date and counting from there would be the best route but I cannot figure out a way to do that within PHP. For example, I can only seem to get the week number of a specific week in the normal calender like so:

```
$date_string = "2012-10-18";
$week = date("W", strtotime($date_string));
echo $week;
```

I appreciate this is probably quite a novice question, I just can't seem to be able to do it! Thank you in advance for any and all help.

Comment: What do you mean by `specify the week from the business year`?

Comment: The business calender starts from the 5th of April this year. I was looking for some way to be able to base the week number from a specific date such as this.

Comment: PHP's `date()` function will only returns week number as for ISO-8601 year. I have never heard of any `business year` in PHP.

Comment: This is why I'm struggling to come up with a week number starting from a specified date. I suppose I could just get the week number and add / remove a certain amount of weeks to it.. Seems pretty ugly though

Comment: By business year, do you mean a business's fiscal year?

Comment: I do indeed, I'll pop that into the description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should just do some date math, i.e. like this (PHP>=5.3 for DateTime::diff is required):

```
<?php
$year_start = new DateTime("2012-03-05");
$date_string = new DateTime("2012-10-18");
$diff = $year_start->diff($date_string);
echo floor($diff->days/7);
```